# Access Denied Error in PagesListCPVEventReceiver post SharePoint SP2 upgrade

Tags: sharepoint

I am seeing the following errors from one of the SharePoint Web Front Ends after the SP2 upgrade.  Has anyone else seen this error or a solution?

```
Event Type: Error
Event Source:   Windows SharePoint Services 3
Event Category: General 
Event ID:   6875
Date:       2009-10-27
Time:       13:09:57
User:       N/A
Computer:   XXXXXXX
Description:
Error loading and running event receiver Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PagesListCPVEventReceiver in Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c. Additional information is below.

: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.
```

Answer (score 0):

refer to these two links for workaround and details

http://yasirbutt.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!A8677D5751E6B4DA!3718.entry

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/948323